# Recommended way to use stopwords with Sphinx

Tags: php, full-text-search, sphinx

I've setup the stopwords as a text file and correctly linked to the location within each index of my sphinf config file - I just wondered what are the 'best' parameters to use with Sphinx API when using a stopwords list.

Note - I am using the PHP Sphinx API

Comment: Not really sure what you asking. There is only one option "stopwords" and you just specifiy the path to your file. Using a stopwords file doesnt affect any of the other options. You just set them as each index requires it.

Comment: cheers barry i worked it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else looking for a solution
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/archives/1.10/conf-stopwords.html